# java.lang.NullPointerException en EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Estoy empezando en el desarrollo con Spring MVC e hibernate.

El sistema se despliega correctamente pero obtengo la siguiente traza de error:

```
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at modelo.RefaccionesDAO.consultarTodo(RefaccionesDAO.java:30)
    at modelo.RefaccionesDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b57106b2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:710)

...
```

cuando se ejecuta este código:

```
@Service //ESTE ES  A FUERZAS.
public class RefaccionesDAO {

    @PersistenceContext //LAS OPERACIONES POR DEFECTO. 
    private EntityManager em;

    //CONTROLA LAS EXEPCIONES. 
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = {ServicioException.class})
    public Refaccion consultarTodo(){
        em.find(Refaccion.class, "10");
        return new Refaccion(1000, "Rafael Angel", 0, 0, "xdafj", "sldfljdf", true);
    }
}
```

La linea especifica es esta: `em.find(Refaccion.class, "10");`

Esta así porque quería descartar que fuera la clase `Refaccion`, pero aun así recibo el error.

Estas son mis configuraciones:

---

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="UNIDAD_DE_PERSISTENCIA_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:app/BASE_DE_DATOS_PRUEBAS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

**aplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"

       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.1.xsd">

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="myEmf" jndi-name="persistence/UNIDAD_DE_PERSISTENCIA_PU" />

<!--    //PERMITE LAS TRANSACCIONES JPA.--> 
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />


    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="entidades" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="modelo" />


</beans>
```

---

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"       
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven /> <!-- Esto es por que vamos a usar MVC de SPRING -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/> <!-- Nos permite trabajar con transacciones JPA -->
    <context:annotation-config /> 


    <!-- Esto escanea los paquetes con los que vamos a trabajar. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="entidades" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="modelo" />


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/otro.htm" view-name="otro"/>  

<!--    <mvc:resources  location="/" mapping="/static/**" />-->

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

---

**ACTUALIZACION**

Desde aquí llamo la inyección de dependencias.

```
@Controller
public class TaponesController {


    @Autowired
    private RefaccionesDAO dao;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/tapones/guardar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String guardarTapon(@RequestParam HashMap<String, String> datos, ModelMap model){

        String text = " testo normal xP : ";
        Refaccion r= dao.consultarTodo();

        text = text +" "+ r.getNombre();

        return text;
    }


}
```

---

## LO QUE HE INTENTADO

---

Cambie el `@PersistenceContext` por esto:

```
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "UNIDAD_DE_PERSISTENCIA_PU", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;
```

Me sigue dando el mismo error.

---

Cambie : `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "UNIDAD_DE_PERSISTENCIA_PU", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)` por esto:

```
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "UNIDAD_DE_PERSISTENCIA_PU")
    private EntityManager em;
```

Obtengo el mismo error.

Comment: Es un escenario extraño: si el DAO está siendo insertado en alguna otra instancia con un @Autowired, si no consigue inyectar una dependencia como el EntityManager, debería darte una excepción antes. ¿Puedes confirmar que no estás creando manualmente la instancia del DAO?

Comment: El DAO lo generé con `@Autowired`. Al final puse el controlador desde donde lo llamo.

Comment: Ya probaste `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "EM", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)` ??

Comment: @abrahamhs No lo he intentado. Probare.

Comment: @abrahamhs Lo cambie pero no me funciono. Me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: @Angel quizas probaste `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "UNIDAD_DE_PERSISTENCIA_PU")`. Sin el parametro type.

Comment: @PatricioBonilla Lo acabo de probar pero me sigue tirando el mismo error. Actualizare la pregunta.

Comment: @Angel hay algo que no me convence en estas lineas de código:
`em.find(Refaccion.class, "10");
        return new Refaccion(1000, "Rafael Angel", 0, 0, "xdafj", "sldfljdf", true);`
La razón es porque si el método retorna un objeto Refaccion, ya lo haces en la linea siguiente: `return new Refaccion(1000, "Rafael Angel", 0, 0, "xdafj", "sldfljdf", true);` . No entiendo el motivo de estar ahi de la linea con `em.find`. Yo la comentaría.

Comment: @PatricioBonilla Lo hize para detectar de donde provenía el error. La ejecución se detiene en `em.find(Refaccion.class, "10"); `  y no devuelve el objeto que yo cree. Si em no estuviera nulo se ejecutaría la llamada a la BD y el código seguiría.

Comment: Yo comente lo del extended por lo que dice aquí https://www.oscarblancarteblog.com/2017/02/21/entitymanager-persistencecontext/ ya que me da la impresión de que no esta inyectando el entity manager, no se si necesites estar en un ejb para que funcione

Comment: @abrahamhs Ok, voy a leerlo. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve investigando bastante y mi problema era que no agregue una dependencia en maven.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Ahora todo funciona correctamente.